# Multiple Google Maps API keys

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We are building two separate applications that will have two different domain names/URLs. Both of these apps with need to utilize a Google Maps API key. Is it OK to register two separate API keys for these two different applications even though they will be built on the same Web Content Management System server? Ex. Create 2 projects in my Google account and generate 2 keys for each project.

We are trying to avoid hitting the 25k limit if we use the same key across both of the applications.
I just want to ensure this isn't against Google's Terms. I don't think it is but want to be sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms of use (legal question) not coding

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's ok to use two different API keys for two different domains. e.g. I work on a site right now that has 11 different keys, for 11 different URLs like

1. foo.example.com
2. bar.example.com
3. abc.example.com

Each of those URLs has its own key.

Comment: Do you know what would happen if on example.com you used few different keys from few differnd google developers acocunts?