# How many Google Maps API Keys do I need?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-api, google-apps, api-key

### The Issue

I haven't actually seen this question addressed adequately anywhere.

I'm using a WordPress plugin that requires a Google Maps API Key. What I'm wondering, is can I use one API Key for all the websites and applications that I manage or do I need a separate API key for each property or app?

For instance, I was pleased to find that I only need one Google Webmaster Tools account which I can use to manage ALL my websites, including ones I've made for an am managing for others.

However, **with Google Maps it's not that clear**. Do I need a separate API Key for every application I make?

### Where I've Looked For Answers So Far:

- [How Google Maps API Keys work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102378/how-google-maps-api-keys-work)
- [Do I need to hide API key when using google maps js API? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153734/do-i-need-to-hide-api-key-when-using-google-maps-js-api-if-so-how)
- [Multiple Google Maps API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677338/multiple-google-maps-api-keys)

What I've pulled from those posts is that you can have multiple API keys, but you don't need *any* API keys, but there are many different *flavors* of Google Maps API keys (huh?) ... it's a bit confusing.

### My Question

If I am making a website for clients A, B, & C does "client-a.com" need a different API Key than "client-b.com"?

### Note

This question is not just about Google Maps, but that was the actual API that brought the confusion about.

Comment: Gotta love when people downvote a question but don't explain why... which kinda makes me think they didn't read the whole question where the very last statement is `If you downvote the question please leave a reason so I know what I need to improve.`  #GOTCHA

Comment: @geocodezip @PRMoureu Although I don't believe this ticket should have been closed because all the questions I asked are different versions of the same question -- they all get at `how many API keys do I need`, and offer multiple contexts and detail within the questions to elicit a wide spectrum of experience and useful perspectives, I made the requested edits to (I believe) `limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer`. Please consider taking this question off hold so that more answers can posted by others who might want to contribute to the conversation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. If I am making a website for clients A, B, & C does "client-a.com" need a different API Key than "client-b.com"?

Typically, yes. You're going to whitelist the various maps API's on a per-domain basis. And you may be rate-limited. It's better for organizational purposes and if you need to pass on fees to a client if you're separating the keys.

> 2. Are there any "go-to" plain-English docs (not tech-manual-ese like a Perl man-page) that explain with good examples (Sitepoint has a really good way of explaining things with conversational writing, and walking you through WHY we do things in programming, not just how) when and where to use API keys and which ones to use?

Google just re-shuffled their Maps platform in a big way. It may take some time for the definitive third-party guides to be written. Here's their [recent announcement](https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html).

> 3. Can I let my friend borrow my API Key to build his app? What are the ramifications of doing such?

Sure you can, but he may impact your rate limits.

> 4. Can I use a Google Maps API key for any other Google app (docs, sheets, YouTube, G+, etc.)? Is a Google API key universal to all apps that integrate/interface with a Google product?

It's just for Google Maps.

Comment: +1 Thanks Dave. I've never heard of rate limits and I studied SEO fro the Moz yellow book in 2016 ... is that an SEO concept, or from some other silo in IT?

Comment: Rate limits are pretty common in the world of APIs. Basically you can only make use of a service X number of times over Y period of time within a certain price tier. If you need more API requests, you need to pay (more).

Comment: Thanks for explaining rate limits. I've never been good with APIs for some reason. I think it is possibly because I understand the term "application programming interface" and exposing functions for the public, but when they created Rest and Soap with the URI-like paths it confused me. Marked your answer as correct.